# How to make this Media Button work after AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have simple editor with TinyMCE loaded by AJAX jQuery. Editor loaded successful but the 'Media Button' not working.

This code for AJAX PHP, find the code from here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/#comment-2273

```
// leave comment
function ajax_leave_comment() {
    global $wpdb, $bbp;

    $reply_id = esc_attr( $_POST['reply_id'] );
    $topic_id = bbp_get_reply_topic_id( $reply_id );

    $temp = '';
    $temp .= bbp_get_the_content( array( 'context' => 'reply-' . $reply_id ) );
    $temp .= \_WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts();
    $temp .= print_footer_scripts();
    $temp .= \_WP_Editors::editor_js();

    echo $temp;
}
```

jQuery AJAX.

```
// leave comment
$( document ).on( 'click', 'button[class*="leave-comment-"]', function(e) {
    var button_comment = $( this );
    var reply_id = button_comment.attr( 'reply-id' );

    var comment_data = {
        action: 'ajax_leave_comment',
        reply_id: reply_id,
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: comment_data,
        dataType: 'html',

        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            button_comment.text( 'Loading...' );
        },

        success: function( response, result, xhr ) {
            button_comment.hide();
            button_comment.after( response );
        }
    });
});
```

Loaded editor screenshot

[image]

And this error on console log if "Media Button" clicked,

[image]

Please explain how to make Media Button working. Thank you.

Comment: can you trace that error (in the error stack trace) to a line of **your** code?

Comment: if i can, i don't create this question :-(

Comment: well ... we can't click on the error to see the stack trace, can we